# how to check if string is an invalid input

Tags: c

I am new to c all the help would be appreciated even if it's just linking me to another forum.

I am writing a very basic program I am taking a 7 digit phone number and placing a "-" in between eg. "1234567" to "123-4567"

I'm looking to check initially if the users phone number is 7 digits long, if not or if any other character besides a number is entered I'd like to display an " Invalid Input" and re-ask the question

Thanks for all the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char phoneNum[6];

   printf("Enter your phone number\n: ");
   scanf("%s", phoneNum);


   printf("Your Phone Number: %.3s", phoneNum);
   printf("-%.4s", phoneNum + 3);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: You're not going to fit a 7-digit number (plus the nul-terminator, of course) into `char phoneNum[6];`. And you want `strlen()`.

Comment: You'll also want to loop through and make sure all of the characters are numbers or a '-'

Answer (score 0):

To store a 7 character string, the character array size must be at least 8 to store the 7 characters and the `\0` character to mark the end of string.
If you intend to store the modified string with the `-` in the same array, the size must be at least 9.

```
char phoneNum[9];
```

And user might enter more than 7 characters to cause overflow.

Try

```
scanf("%7s", phoneNum);
```

To find if the string is all numbers, use a loop

```
for(i=0; phoneNum[i]!='\0'; ++i)
{
    if(!isdigit(phoneNum[i]))
    {
        break;
    }
}
if(phoneNum[i]!='\0')
{
    printf("\nInvalid input.");
}
```

To find the length of the string, use `strlen()`.

To insert a `-` at the 3rd index of string, you must shift all indices from that index till the end of string (including the `\0` character).

```
for(i=8; i>3; --i)
{
    phoneNum[i]=phoneNum[i-1];
}
phoneNum[3]='-';
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to check initially if the users phone number is 7 digits long, if not or if any other character besides a number is entered.

Avoid `scanf("%s", phoneNum);`.  It is not limited in the amount it reads, does not read an entire *line* (misses spaces), and leaves the line's `'\n'` in `stdin`.

Use a large enough buffer for the job.  No need to be stingy.  Recommend a buffer  2x expected needs.

```
// Make a function to read a number and ask for input
char *read_phone(char *buf, size_t size, const char *prompt) {
  char *reprompt = "";
  while (1) {
    printf("%s%s", reprompt, prompt);
    reprompt = " Invalid Input";  // ready re-prompt should code iterate
    fflush(stdout); // Insure output is seen

    // Read a line of user input in as a string.
    if (fgets(buf, size, stdin) == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }

    // For OP to do, iterate with `i` through buf[] insuring expected pattern
    int i = 0;
    // next lines pseudo code
    if (!OP_code_pattern(buf)) {
      continue;  // try again
    }

    // If at end-of-line, lop it off
    if (buf[i] == '\n') {
      buf[i] = '\0';
    }

    // If at end of string - success
    if (buf[i] == '\0') {
      return buf;
    }
  }
```